# PHP XML Parsing, multiple 'index' issue

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am parsing the data below using a php foreach loop, I need to pull out data from measuredValue index 2 and index 3 however I am not sure how to do this. The code below shows what I am using to pull the data from the XML file. I have got to airTemperature working which is in 'index 1' but I cannot figure out how to get into the next 'index' section.

```
foreach ($weather_array->payloadPublication->siteMeasurements as $roaddt){

    echo ("
        <tr>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measurementSiteReference. "</td>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measurementTimeDefault. "</td>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measuredValue->basicDataValue->temperature->airTemperature. "</td>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measuredValue->basicDataValue->wind->windDirectionCompass. "</td>
        </tr> ");
}
echo "</table>";
```

The code below is part what I am trying to pull from:

```
<siteMeasurements>
    <measurementSiteReference>NRA10810</measurementSiteReference>
    <measurementTimeDefault>2017-02-28T15:50:00+00:00</measurementTimeDefault>
    <measuredValue index="1">
    <basicDataValue xsi:type="TemperatureInformation">
    <period>3600</period>
    <temperature>...</temperature>
    </basicDataValue>
    </measuredValue>
    <measuredValue index="2">
    <basicDataValue xsi:type="PrecipitationInformation">
    <period>3600</period>
    <precipitationDetail></precipitationDetail>
    </basicDataValue>
    </measuredValue>
    <measuredValue index="3">
    <basicDataValue xsi:type="WindInformation">
    <period>3600</period>
    <wind>
    <maximumWindSpeed>45</maximumWindSpeed>
    <windDirectionBearing>302</windDirectionBearing>
    <windDirectionCompass>westNorthWest</windDirectionCompass>
    <windSpeed>27.4</windSpeed>
    </wind>
    </basicDataValue>
    </measuredValue>
```

Comment: how is the XML being read (i.e. how is `$weather_array` assigned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only loop on `siteMeasurements`, but each `siteMeasurements` has multiple `measuredValue`.
So within your existing loop you need to add another loop on `measuredValue`. Something like that :

```
foreach ($weather_array->payloadPublication->siteMeasurements as $roaddt){
     echo ("
        <tr>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measurementSiteReference. "</td>
            <td> " .$roaddt->measurementTimeDefault. "</td>");
    foreach ($roaddt->measuredValue as $mValue){
     echo ("<td> " .$mValue->basicDataValue. "</td>");               
    }
    echo ("</tr>");
}
```